# UWP adaptive triggers usage

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm currently working on a new UWP application.

I have a question about screen design technique.
What is the best option with triggers and mobile/computer screens ?

**Option 1 :**

As seen on a lot of tuto, use the triggers to set a lot of properties. We will get a code like the following :

```
<VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="IngredientsPanel.(Grid.Row)" Value="0" />
    <Setter Target="IngredientsPanel.(Grid.Column)" Value="1" />
    <Setter Target="DirectionsPanel.(Grid.Row)" Value="0" />
    <Setter Target="DirectionsPanel.(Grid.Column)" Value="2" />
    <Setter Target="ImagePanel.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="1" />
    <Setter Target="IngredientsPanel.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="1" />
    <Setter Target="DirectionsPanel.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="1" />
</VisualState.Setters>
```

This option give you a lot of Setter element, who can be hard de debug and place correctly.

**Option 2 :**

Use setter to show and hide a specific Grid for each resolution type. 
The initial idea was from MVA [(link)](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/advanced-windows-store-app-development-using-c-jump-start-12648?l=Iu0wAtBTB_9700115888) and seems to work perfectly with MVVM.
It would give you the following code :

```
<VisualState.Setters>
   <Setter Target="MyFirstColumnGrid.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
</VisualState.Setters>
```

What is the best option ? Are they viable with a lot of UI element ? And can you provide me example to confirm your explication ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point of view, the state manager is good for when you don't have too many changes on a view because as you mention, when changing many properties it can become kind of a mess.

If your view will change A LOT between devices, I would recommend using the `device family name` with the `XAML view` template item:

[image]

The XAML view is nothing more than a `XAML` view (duh!) that has no code behind associated with it by default, this is typically used for controls and/or different devices.

So how do you use it?

You create a `Blank Page`, add all the code behind you need for it (or set the data context to point to your view model) and then create a `XAML View` with the same name plus the device family name.

For example:

[image]

As you can see, there is a `MainPage` and a `MainPage.DeviceFamily-Mobile.xaml`, check the mobile version, which has no code behind (the expand icon on the left side of the name is missing).

This means that when your application is loaded in mobile devices, it will use the XAML only view (which as code behind will load the one from the standard MainPage). In any other case, the standard MainPage will be used.

The concept is basically the same as with localized resource files or even similar to partial classes, only with XAML views and based on the device family names.

You can find more info on [this link](http://igrali.com/2015/08/02/three-ways-to-set-specific-devicefamily-xaml-views-in-uwp/).

Comment: As you said, there is no code-behind. So if I use MVVM, this process is perfect for a device specific resolution. Are they any performence issues ?

Comment: There should be no issues whatsoever. The only thing that changes is the size of your package (you have an extra view vs extra lines of code for the state manager). MVVM works great in this case as you just have one line of code in the code behind (data context setting), or not even that if you declare it as a Page Resource!